# Immersive mode throws exception in NDK even though it is called from main thread

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, google-play-games, ui-thread

When I try to set sticky immersive mode via JNI using the Java method "`setSystemUiVisibility`" the exception *"Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.*" is thrown.
However, the function is called right when I get the `APP_CMD_GAINED_FOCUS`/`APP_CMD_RESUME` message, which according to the documentation is sent from the main thread.

My assumption is that the thread where the views are created (supposedly the *UI-thread*) and the *NDK* main thread the same thread, so why do I get this exception?

Note that this exception isn't always thrown, only when I resume program under special circumstances such as *Google Play Games* services ui's are launched.